# Prove that $10 | (n^a - n^b)$.

Tags: induction, divisibility

$n$ is a positive integer. Prove that there exists positive integers $a$ and $b$, $(a > b)$ such that $10 | (n^a - n^b)$.

I have tried to prove this by induction on $n$, but I get stuck at the induction step trying to prove it for $n = k + 1$, not knowing how to expand $((k + 1)^a - (k + 1)^b)$. Is this the wrong approach to solving this problem, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you know about integers mod "n" ?

Comment: Very little about it; would I be looking at if $n$ divided $a - b$?

Comment: $a=5$ and $b=1$ seem to work.

Comment: Ah! Bang on; I just need to formalize a proof as to why now. Thank you!

Comment: Nvm, its easier than that. Pick the last digit of $n^a$, and move $b$ from $a+1$ to $a+10$. Since there are 10 digits, use the pigeonhole principle to conclude

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem would be my suggestion though this may be overkill in some classes.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment by [Akiva Weinberger](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/166353/akiva-weinberger), take $a=5$ and $b=1$.

Then $(k+1)^a-(k+1)^b=(k+1)^5-(k+1)=(k+1)[(k+1)^4-1]$

$=(k+1)(k^4+4k^3+6k^2+4k)=(k+1)k(k^3+4k^2+6k+4)$.

This is divisible by $2$ because  $(k+1)k$ is,

and modulo $5$ this is the same as $(k+1)k(k-1)(k^2+1)$, so it is divisible by $5$ too,

and therefore it is divisible by $10$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $n^{a} - n^{b} \equiv 0\pmod 2$ since if $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ , then $ n^{a} - n^{b}\equiv 1-1 \equiv 0\pmod 2$ and if $n\equiv 0 \pmod 2, n^{a} - n^{b}\equiv0-0 \equiv 0\pmod 2$.

If $5|n$, then $n^{a}-n^{b}\equiv0-0\equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and so $10|n^{a}-n^{b}$.

If $5 \nmid n$, then $n^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ by Fermat's little theorem so that $n^{8} \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \implies$

$n^{8}-n^{4} \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and altogether, in this case, $10|n^{a}-n^{b}$ as well where $a=8$ and $b=4$.